# which method simply a specific inner for loop? Using cell or other method

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

I am working on a on-line sequential algorithm. At time `t`, I receive a data vector `y` of length `t`, and I need to check each element in `y`. For the newest obs `y(t)`has impact on the judgement for all previous obs, so even at each time only one new obs `y(t)` is received, the whole vector `y` needs to be checked. Here is my current solution, and of course the whole observation `y(1:t)` is pre-generated:

```
   for i = 1:length(y)%%length(y) = t
     for j = 1:i
        p(i,j) = fct(y(1:j),y(j+1:i))
     end
   end
```

I am thinking for at time t, the only difference in the inner `for` loop is the segmentation of data `y(1:j)` and `y(j+1:t)`, so if it constructing a `t*2` size cell `c` with `c{t,1} = y(1:j)` and `c{t,2} = y(j:t)` could make the process faster. I know using cell cause lot of overhead, and is there any better way?

Comment: What is `fct` and how does it work? Actually, I don't see how you expect cells to speed this up at all. Can you elaborate?

Comment: And how does the loop not do the same thing for each `i`? Is there some randomness involved in `fct`? Or did you mean to write `i` instead of `t` in the loop?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Sorry for the typo. `fct` is a self-defined function. I am not 100% expecting a cell approach can give me much improvement. Using cell could save the inner `for` loop, but also brings overhead.

Comment: Cells don't support vectorization: you have to loop over them or use`cellfun` which is a loop plus overhead. I believe your best chance is vectorizing `fct` itself, so that you don't have to loop over, say, `j`. Is the function very complex?

Comment: @AndrasDeak `fct` is quite complex. I don't get what you mean by vectorizing `fct`. The input of `fct` is 2 segments of data, so saying 'vectorizing' you mean vectorizing the input?

Comment: By vectorizing it I meant making it possible to work its way through multiple segments simultaneously, with using array operations or `bsxfun` instead of loops utside.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I will try to use like `bsxfun(@fct, data, cut_off)`, i.e. `data = y(1:t)` and `cut_off = 1:t`. Is that what you suggested?

Comment: No, and that won't work.

Comment: can you give me a short example?

Comment: No. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​